# Rails, ActiveRecord: how do I get the results of an association plus some condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have two models, user and group. I also have a joining table groups_users.
I have an association in the group model:

```
has_many :groups_users
has_many :users, :through=> :groups_users
```

I would like to add pending_users which would be the same as the users association but contain some conditions. I wish to set it up as an association so that all the conditions are handled in the sql call. I know there's a way to have multiple accessors for the same model, even if the name is not related to what the table names actually are. Is it class_name?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be pretty close - more on [has_many](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001833).

```
has_many :pending_users, 
         :through => :groups_users, 
         :source => :users, 
         :conditions => {:pending => true}
```

:pending is probably called something else - however you determine your pending users. As a side note - usually when you see a user/group model the association is called membership.

Answer (score 2):

#### Use `named_scope`s, they're your friend

Have you tried using a `named_scope` on the `Group` model?

Because everything is actually a proxy until you actually need the data, 
you'll end up with a single query anyway if you do this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :pending, :conditions => { :status => 'pending' }
```

and then:

```
a_group.users.pending
```

#### Confirmation

I ran the following code with an existing app of mine:

```
Feature.find(6).comments.published
```

It results in this query (ignoring the first query to get feature 6):

```
SELECT    * 
FROM      `comments` 
WHERE     (`comments`.feature_id = 6) 
  AND     ((`comments`.`status` = 'published') AND (`comments`.feature_id = 6))
ORDER BY  created_at
```

And here's the relevant model code:

```
class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many    :comments

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :feature
  named_scope :published, :conditions => { :status => 'published' }
```

Comment: Declare the pending in the User model, not the Group
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  named_scope :pending...
end

Answer (score 0):

In the User model:

```
named_scope :pending, :include => :groups_users, :conditions => ["group_users.pending = ?", true]
```

That's if you have a bool column named "pending" in the join table group_users.

Edit:
Btw, with this you can do stuff like:

```
Group.find(id).users.pending(:conditions => ["insert_sql_where_clause", arguments])
```